# mysql command to exchange columns

Tags: mysql

I ran into a problem where one version of my database has a column that is in the wrong position.  Is there a way in mysql to re-index or exchange columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CHANGE old_col new_col integer AFTER sec_col
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! I think I could use modify as well and not need the new_col name.  You guys are way faster than Google and MySQL's website!